# Why does my jquery span text change fail when the value is not alerted?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a function that updates the text of a span using select menu values or select menu selected text. it doesn't work 100% of the time. I'm using Jquery 1.7.2. It works like a champ in Chrome but fails Miserably in IE9.

```
// note: the onchange of each select box sets all other select boxes to "X"   
 if ($("#dd1").val() != "X") { $('#reportType').val($("#dd1").val()); }
            if ($("#dd2").val() != "X") { $('#reportType').val($("#dd2").val()); }
            if ($("#dd3").val() != "X") { $('#reportType').val( $("#dd3").val()); }
            if ($("#dd4").val() != "X") { $('#reportType').val( $("#dd4").find(":selected").text()); }
 //assign to span...
 $("#myspan").text(" - " + $("#reportType").val());
```

Strangely enough if I alert the value directly before updating the span I get the expected value...

Comment: Might help if you post the relevant HTML code fragment too

Comment: A learned a valuable lesson after lots of wasted time doing of guess work. When in doubt go back to plain Javascript. This seems to be working great:  `document.getElementById('myspan').innerHTML = $("#dd2").val()`.